# Bluetooth low energy for Samsung Galaxy S3 and TI CC2540 heart rate monitor

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, broadcom

I am developing a bluetooth low energy application for the Samsung Galaxy S3. I am using 
Broadcom ble jar file into my project.  I am able to search the TI CC2540 ble device.

But when I try to connect the Galaxy S3 to CC2540, I immediately get a null pointer 
exception and I am not able to connect to it. I tried many times but I am not able
to connect to it. Below is the line of code in my application which connects to the remote ble device.

```
mFindMe.connect(mDevice);
```

`mfindme` is my HRM profile and `mDevice` is the bluetooth address of my CC2540 TI ble device.

It always throws a null pointer exception when I try to connect to the device.

Comment: full stack, more surounding code.

Comment: please provide any help with working example for bluetooth low energy for samsung galaxy s3. i have update my galaxy s3 with jelly bean 4.1. i am able to search TI ble module. but when i m try to connect it always failed. broadcom ble is really stucking and helpless in android.

Comment: Can you please share your experience with S3 and Broadcom ble jar file ? I'm blocked on a "no method found BleAdapter.getDeviceType"...

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code for my project. I hope it helps you to understand my problem.

```
btconnect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_connect);
btconnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        try
        {
            mFindMe.connect(mDevice);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Error","connecting");
        }
    }
});

setUiState();
registerReceiver(regReceiver, new IntentFilter(FindMeProfileClient.FINDME_REGISTERD));

mDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(HRM_BD_ADDRESS);
mFindMe = new FindMeProfileClient(this);
```

I have also found that the `public static final String BLUETOOTH_LE_SERVICE` is missing in the broadcom jar file so `mservice` variable is null.

Please kindly provide any help on this bluetooth low energy profile.

Comment: Did any one have any answer to this question as i m really stucking in this android with bluetooth low energy.